# WKWebView javascript method click() does nothing

Tags: javascript, swift, web-crawler, wkwebview

In my xcode project I'm trying to click on a link using javascript through WKWebView, this should be the right code, however it isn't doing what it's supposed to. I have other lines of javascript code that get the innerHTML and input values work without any issues, there is also no problem loading the site.

I've tried modifying my code by adding a semi-colon at the end, using a capital c (in click), changing the program to look by tag instead of class, and trying the same line of code in UIWebView which still doesn't work

```
let webView = WKWebView()

let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")
webView.load(URLRequest(url:url!))
//A button activates the latter code, the site has been successfully loaded 
//before I press it

//I have other lines of code like this that will change values, submit 
//forms, etc. this line of code doesn't do anything
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementByTagName('a')[0].click()", 
completionHandler: nil)
```

I want this line of code to click on the first link, and redirect me to that page, instead the code leaves me on the page I started without preforming the click action. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

1. document has not Load completely. try this `alert(document.getElementsByTagName('a').length)`
   Wait for the document to be fully loaded before executing
2. you must check click event is already bind